# How can I go through a list of equities tickers to update a dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, list

I'm really new to Python and this question might be too basic that I cannot seem to find any answers online at the moment.

I have been trying to loop through a list of 9 equity tickers, called 'symbol' below, to retrieve each ticker's balance sheet, cash flow statement, and income statement from YahooFinancials.

Been using `for symbol in ecommerce():` to create a loop, but received the TypeError below.

```
    from yahoofinancials import YahooFinancials
    import pandas as pd
    import requests
    import numpy as np
    from datetime import datetime

    ecommerce = ['CTRP', 'EBAY', 'GRUB', 'BABA', 'JD', 'EXPE', 'AMZN', 'BKNG', 'MPNGF']

    for symbol in ecommerce():
        df_income_statement = scrape_table('https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/' + symbol + '/financials?p=' + symbol)
        df_income_statement

        df_cash_flow = scrape_table('https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/' + symbol + '/cash-flow?p=' + symbol)
        df_cash_flow

        balance_sheet_url = 'https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/' + symbol + '/balance-sheet?p=' + symbol
        df_balance_sheet = scrape_table(balance_sheet_url)
```

Expected results: dataframe with balance sheets of 'CTRP', 'EBAY', 'GRUB', 'BABA', 'JD', 'EXPE', 'AMZN', 'BKNG', 'MPNGF'

```
TypeError: 'list' object is not callable

from yahoofinancials import YahooFinancials import pandas as pd import requests import numpy as np from datetime import datetime

ecommerce = ['CTRP', 'EBAY', 'GRUB', 'BABA', 'JD', 'EXPE', 'AMZN', 'BKNG', 'MPNGF']

for symbol in ecommerce(): df_income_statement = scrape_table('https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/' + symbol + '/financials?p=' + symbol) df_income_statement
```

Comment: Why do you have parentheses in `for symbol in ecommerce()`? `ecommerce` is a list, and when you put those parentheses it tells python to attempt to "call" it like a function or method, hence the "Not callable" error

Comment: Thank you so much for the explanation, clear now :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you write `ecommerce()` Python assumes you want to call a function (callable) which is referenced by the name `ecommerce`, but what you want to do is iterate over the list (ecommerce contains a list).

So you just need to remove the (). You can start with something like:

```
for symbol in ecommerce: 
    income_statement_dataframes= pd.read_html('https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/' + symbol + '/financials?p=' + symbol)
```

With this code `income_statement_dataframes` should contain a list of dataframes. One dataframe per html table on the webpage referenced by the url.
You just need to check, which one of the tables it is. If you are lucky you can use it already this way. If you can't find the table in a usable form among the elements of the list (e.g. if the html is a bit more wicked), you can have a look at BeautifulSoup (import bs4).

Comment: Thank you so much for the detailed explanation, it works! :)